# How to get Date format when write to excel sheet using grails2.3.7

Tags: java, grails, export, export-to-excel, grails-plugin

There is value in data table.
column is Order Date and format is like **2014-11-06 20:27:40**.
when we export by using below code.

```
response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.formattext]
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Manual Order list.${params.formattext}")

List fields = ["orderDate","id","firstName","account","paymentMode","transactionId"]
Map labels = ["orderDate":"OrderDate","id":"Order No","firstName":"Customer Name",
             "account":"Account", "paymentMode":"Payment Method",
             "transactionId":"Transaction Id"]
//Map parameters = [OrderType: "User Order", "column.widths": [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]]
exportService.export(params.formattext, response.outputStream,userOrderCriteria?.list{between("orderDate",d1,d2)}, 
                     fields, labels, [:], [:])
```

Then In excel Sheet Order Date value is **27:40** means minute and second only.
please help me. How can I get complete format as saved in data table.